# How to get all rows between two dates with laravel queries?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm working on a reservation system for hotels where the user inserts check-in and checkout date then he finds all hotels and rooms available in this period meanwhile in the backend I set contracts where I identify in each the prices for the room during a specific period.

The database query should include every contract valid through this period and every day in this period should be covered by a contract.

**Hotel with contracts query:**

```
Hotel::with(["contracts" => function($query) use($from, $to, $columns) {
    $query->select(
    "contracts.*",
    DB::raw("SUM(contract_rooms.we_price) as total_we_price"),
    DB::raw("SUM(contract_rooms.wd_price) as total_wd_price"))
        ->whereBetween("contracts.to_time" , [$from, $to])
        ->orWhereBetween("contracts.from_time" , [$from, $to])
        ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($from, $to){
            $query->where("contracts.from_time", "<", $from)
                ->where("contracts.to_time", ">", $to);
        })
        ->join("contract_rooms", "contracts.id", "=", "contract_rooms.contract_id")
        ->groupBy("contract_rooms.view_id", "contract_rooms.meal_id", "contracts.room_type_id")
        ->orderBy("contract_rooms.wd_price","ASC");
            }, "reviews"])
        ->whereHas("contracts", function ($query) use ($from, $to) {
            $query->whereBetween("contracts.to_time" , [$from, $to])
                ->orWhereBetween("contracts.from_time" , [$from, $to])
                ->where(function ($query) use ($from, $to) {
                    $query->where("contracts.from_time", "<", $from)
                        ->where("contracts.to_time", ">", $to);
                    });
                });
```

**Hotels Table:**

```
+------------------+-----------+-------------+
| id | hotel_name  | city_id   | description |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------------+
|  1 |  Hilton     | 1         | Text        |
|  2 |  Sheraton   | 1         | Text        |
|  3 |  Aston      | 1         | Text        |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------------+
```

**RoomType Table:**

```
+--------------+-----------+------+
| id | name    | room_size | beds |
+----+---------+-----------+------+
|  1 |  text   | 0         | 2    |
|  2 |  text   | 1         | 2    |
|  3 |  text   | 0         | 2    |
+--------------+-----------+------+
```

**Contracts Table:**

```
+-------------+-----------+--------------+------------+-------------+
| id | name   | hotel_id  | room_type_id | from_time  | to_time     |
+----+--------+-----------+--------------+------------+-------------+
|  1 | text   | 1         | 1            | 2020-10-14 |  2020-10-20 |
|  2 | text   | 1         | 1            | 2020-10-21 |  2020-10-30 |
|  3 | text   | 1         | 1            | 2020-11-05 |  2020-11-20 |
+----+--------+-----------+--------------+------------+-------------+
```

> **For example:**
>
> - if the user enters dates between 14/10/2020 & 30/10/2020 he gets the first 2 rows.
> - if the user enters two dates between 14/10/2020 & 14/11/2020 he gets nothing.

Comment: Use whereDate clause

Comment: That is good, but I want to check a condition that all dates are connected with no gaps between all contracts.

Comment: Have you tried whereBetween?
I think this can satisfy what you ara looking for.

Comment: I'm already using it in the query I provided above.